# How to deal with missing libraries on Linux? [No Admin privileges and PIP is blocked]

Tags: python, redhat, pyside

For my work I need to write a GUI using PySide6 for a remote system. The OS is RHEL 7.9 and I have neither admin privileges nor PIP working (blocked by admins), so i can't install anything by myself (and i'm not allowed to anyways).

The script runs perfectly on Windows and Fedora, but it doesn't work on RHEL 7.9:

1. Since the machine doesn't allow pip, I've included PySide6 in my virtual environment, but there are missing libraries in the system itself, like CXXABI_1.3.9 and GLIBC_2.33 that Shiboken6 needs.
2. It also didn't work in compiled form (with PyInstaller) because the GLIBC_2.29 is missing.
3. Naively I copied libstdc++.so.6 and libc.so.6 from a Fedora machine to RHEL and redirected the linking to the libraries with the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, but because of other dependencies it didn't work.

Is there a solution to make the script work cross-platform and independently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't answer your question about the missing libraries, but I hope it helps solve your current issue with PySide.

I've had a similar problem before, you should always develop on the target platform to get comparable results.
This means that you theoretically have to write, compile and package your program on the RHEL machine. You also need to always develop on the older platform. Forward compatibility is not always guaranteed. I therefore suggest, that you install CentOS 7 in a virtual machine and if your program is not too complicated try to use PySide2 instead of PySide6.

Answer (score 1):

One way may be to put the (binary) files in the user bin.
The path for that (at least on my system) is `/home/.local/bin`

Make sure this is in your `$PATH` variable, if it isn't already (it should be).

If these are just Python modules, you can just drag the source file into the aforementioned path (make sure they have a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) so they run). If not, you may have to compile them and then put them there.

#### Explaination of local bin

Note: This is from my experience

The local bin (`/home/.local/bin`) is where you can put programs you want to run without installing them globally. It's similar to doing `./file.py`, except you don't need to be in the same directory as the file (and you don't have to include `./`) I assume, if you include a compiled version of the dependencies you want, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, that helped with another issue i had. But my problem here is that essential libraries are missing from the system itself because it's not up to date (and I'm not allowed/can't update it). PySide6 (like probably other modules) does not contain all necessary files and uses the standard libraries e.g. /lib64/libstdc++.so.6.

Comment: @Niemand Is it possible to put an up-to-date version of these packages in your user bin?

Comment: Yes, i can put files in /home/.local/bin, but some dependencies are missing form the system itself and i can't get all needed files since some are system specific like ld-linux-x86-64.so.2. The python packeges themselves unfortunately don't have all needed dependencies included.